# Newly created file becames ".gz" automatically?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, vim

I was creating new file with "**vim a.txt**" in `/var/lib` directory but after I am saving the same file with `vim`, It becames "**a.txt.gz**".

Also tried with `fallocate -l 1M a.log` still it creates **a.log.gz**

I am not getting what was happening to that directory only, elsewhere at other location its creating with just name which I gave **a.txt**

Comment: Do you have anything similar to `logrotate` installed and potentially misconfigured to process files in `/var/lib` ?

Comment: yes `logrotate` configured on that

Comment: How does it affect the directory, by zipping the newly created file?? @viraptor

Comment: @Miracle I'd guess it actually does the compression on file close.

Comment: yes but why on that specific directory @AndrewHenle

Comment: @Miracle I'd bet "yes `logrotate` configured on that" has something to do with it.